# What is the difference between an "enumeration type" and an "enumerated type" in C++?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, enumeration

The Standard "apparently" defines "enumeration type" in [dcl.enum]/[1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.enum#1). The term "enumerated type" is defined [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/enumerated.types).

Comment: The same thing.

Comment: It appears to be here _"[an] enumerated type may be implemented as an enumeration or as a synonym for an enumeration."_

Comment: It's in your last link.  *Each enumerated type may be implemented as an enumeration or as a synonym for an enumeration.* says it's something that is or acts like an enum

Comment: @DrewDormann What do they mean by a "synonym for an enumeration"?

Comment: `typedef` or `using`, basically.

Comment: The second rule of statutory construction is “read on”.. The text you link to has a footnote. Read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first link (http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.enum#1) explains what an enumeration type in C++ is. This is where C++ officially defines it.

The other link (http://eel.is/c++draft/enumerated.types) is about the C++ standard library. This link explains how you have to read the description of the standard library, that comes in the subsequent chapters.

For example in chapter 29 there is the description of a type `ios_base::seekdir`:

> The type seekdir is an enumerated type (16.3.3.3.3) that contains the elements indicated in Table 120.

And then they explain that there are three possible values `beg`, `cur` `end`. This may be intuitive enough for most people who want to use that library of chapter 29. But as this enumeration type is part of the public interface of that library, others may think, that just saying there are three possible values is not precise enough. The reader must precisely know what comes out of a function that returns an seekdir.

And therefore your second link clearly explains what they mean, when saying "it is an enumerated type that contains these elements."

The wording "synonym of enumeration" means that exactly the same thing (the same bits and bytes), that is provided by an enumeration type, can be also be provided by other types. If for example you have a function that returns an enum with one=1, two=2, three=3, you are free to see the returned value as an element of that enum type or just as an integer. At library level there is no difference between both interpretations of the bits that are coming out of such a function. The interpretation comes only when you include a header file, where the function is precisely defined together with its return type.

The reason why in the second link there is not only the definition of the enum type but also the definition of the constants is that at library level the individual elements (the numbers) of the enum are not visible. At library level it is only visible, that there is an integer. But when you want to use a library you must know the individual values. In order to achieve this, the library oxposes them as constants.

Comming back to the `seekdir` type, with your second link it is clarified that it will be this type:

```
enum enumerated { beg, cur, end };

inline const enumerated beg(beg);
inline const enumerated cur(cur);
inline const enumerated end(end);
```

With these inlined constants you can find out what numbers are actually behind the enum without having the header file.

Comment: I don't understand what you wrote above: "`...`at library level the individual elements (the numbers) of the `enum` are not visible". Why are they not visible in the library?

Comment: When you (for example) link a shared library and in that library there is a function that returns an enum type, all you can see is, that there is a function that returns a byte. You cannot say if that byte is is an enum, a char or a number. This is how libraries work. You only know more if you have compiled the library with debug symbols (which is normally not the case) or when you also have the header file, where you can look at the type definition. But the type definition itself is not part of the library. This is why you normally need the header file when linking something.

Comment: But in case you have no header file and no debug symbols, the constants help you. These really appear in the library as constants and are visible. They have a name and everybody can see what the corresponding values are.

Answer (score 1):

An actual enumeration consists of two parts: the type and the enumerators defined by that type.

An "enumerated type" consists of *three* parts: the enumeration type, the enumerators of that enumeration type, and the *elements* of the enumerat**ed** type. The elements are names which are of the enumeration type and resolve to one of the enumerators within that enumeration. Now, you may notice that every enumeration is an "enumerated type", so long as its elements match the names required by the enumerated type's requirements.

But they don't have to actually be one of the enumerators. You can see that in the example you linked to:

```
enum enumerated { V0, V1, V2, V3, … };

inline const enumerated C0(V0);
inline const enumerated C1(V1);
inline const enumerated C2(V2);
inline const enumerated C3(V3);
...
```

This is one way to implement enumerated types. The standard would require the elements of the enumerated type to be `C0`, `C1`, etc., and the enumerated type could hide the actual enumerators of `enumerated` (ie `V0`, `V1`, etc).

The main reason for this concept is the next section: [the definition of a "bitmask type"](http://eel.is/c++draft/bitmask.types). Bitmasks are enumerated types (as defined above), but they have extra functionality to perform bit-wise operations (which basic enumerations don't have by default).

Comment: What is the advantange of using `C0`, `C1`, and so on, instead of `V0`, `V1`, and so on? I don't understand it from the last paragraph of your answer.

Comment: @Enlico: How about `namespace A { enum Colors { Red = 1, Blue = 2, Purple = 3 }; }` vs `namespace B { enum Colors { Red = 1, Blue = 2 }; inline const Colors Purple{Red | Blue}; }`

Comment: @BenVoigt, I don't get it. In the second case you define `Colors` to be inhabitaed by 2 value only, `Red` and `Blue`, then you try to define another value which is none of the two. What does that mean? By the way, the second example doesn't even compile because `Red | Blue` is an `int` rvalue.

Comment: Basically I have the same question as @Enlico's first comment above. What is the purpose of having `C0, ... , C3` hiding `V0, ... , V3` ?

Comment: The reason is that the constants are visible at library level. Everybody who uses the library can see them. If you just have an enum without the constants, everybody sees only, that there is an integer and the actual numbers are then implementation details.

Comment: Oh, I see now. `V0`, `V1`, ... are just literals of type `enumerated` (just like `1`, `"hello"` and `true` are litarals of type `int`, `char const*`, and `bool`). Whereas `C0`, `C1`, ... are actual variables (though `const`, so not really variable).

Comment: Well, even though apprently [they are not classified as "literals"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions#Literals).